# Creating a trigger which enters value in studies(rollno,code) table only if total credits of a student are less than 30

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am getting the error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER db BEFORE INSERT ON studies
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF((select CAST(SUM(credits) as UNSIGNED) from ((SELECT credits from subject WHERE subject.code = NEW.code) union all (SELECT credits from subject,(SELECT code from studies where studies.rollno = NEW.rollno) as t1 WHERE subject.code = t1.code)) as t2) > 30) THEN
    set NEW.rollno = NULL;
    ENDIF;
    END
```

Comment: try this- set NEW.rollno = NULL,